# Any documentation for optimizing the performance of R?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm fairly new to R, and one thing that has struck me is that it's running fairly slow. Is there any documentation for optimizing R? For example, optimizing Python is described very good [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips). In my particular case I'm interested in optimizing R for batch jobs.

I have tried Googling for an answer of course, but it's not exactly easy to Google for R info since R is a pretty generic little search pattern.

Comment: @c00kiemonster, a lot of what goes for MATLAB, in terms of optimization, also goes for R. It's not a procedural language and so trying to do things procedurally is a recipe for frustration. For example, avoid **for** loops over more than, say, 1000 indices, at all costs in R. (They're at least one, and likely two, orders of magnitude slower than even MATLAB.) Use the **apply** functions wherever you can since the looping happens at a lower level and is, thus, much more efficient. Also, R's memory manager is generally poor, so be aware of that, too.

Comment: Instead of Google, try http://rseek.org/ .

Comment: @c00kiemonster, this question is more suited for stackoverflow. Remember that poorly written code runs slow everywhere. I myself find R pretty speedy, few times rewriting something C did not bring immense benefits. In general you should provide more context, since for a lot of people R is pretty fast, so your experience may be an outlier.

Comment: I'm sure it will get more and better answers here.

Comment: This question has been discussed in several threads, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330944/speed-of-r-programming-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, R is a bit awkward for a search term, so try RSiteSearch("performance") within R - this will search within lots of R docs sources.

Answer (score 9):

For start, you should take a look at [R Inferno by Patric Burns](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Than the best idea is to ask more detailed questions here.

Answer (score 3):

a simple google search on 'efficient programming in r' reveals the following excellent resources. the first resource is great as it provides a comparison of the bad, good and best ways of programming a task in R. the second resource is more generic.

1. http://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0044882/Research/slidesR.pdf
2. http://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2010/BioC2010/EfficientRProgramming.pdf

if you are looking at more specific areas of optimizing your R code, specify it more clearly and i am sure you will find an expert here !!

Comment: now the first one is broken :)

Answer (score 2):

"It's running fairly slow" is very vague. There are many techniques for using R in the most efficient way, the general rule is "avoid loops, and vectorize" - but there is so much more such as ensuring objects are pre-allocated rather than resized on the fly.

It really depends on what you are doing, so please be more specific. The standard documentation has plenty of tips for the basics and your question does not really give opportunity for someone to do any more than regurgitate those.

When standard R really is limited for your needs you can write directly in a compiled language such as C, or use advanced interfaces such as Rcpp. For other tools and techniques that extend beyond the basic R toolkit consult the "High Performance Computing" Task View on CRAN.